# SQL - Inserting data into a table using a join

Tags: sql, teradata

I have created a table and want to insert data into this table from another table using a join.  The problem I am having is that table 2 is massive, 100s of millions of rows, so when I run my query I always get an error message "2646 no more spool space".

This is a example of the query I was trying to use, I have already created the empty column in my table.

```
INSERT INTO database1.table1 (empty column)
SELECT desiredcolumn
FROM database2.table2
INNER JOIN database1.table1
on table1.column = table2.column
```

Thanks

Comment: Try splitting your data in more managable chunks based on a key field: eg: go 1 million row by 1 million row

Comment: Based on your comments you want to Update a newly added column. What are the Primary Indexes of both tables? And how many rows (and columns) are in table1? Can you show the Explain for the Select part only?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually rinning it 10 million by 10 million splitting on ID

<del>INSERT INTO database1.table1 (empty_column) 
    SELECT desiredcolumn 
            from            database2.table2 
                 INNER JOIN database1.table1 on table1.column = table2.column
    where table1.id <10 000 000
    and table1.id > 0</del>

then launch it several times until you did all the records

EDIT AFTER LEARNING TABLE 1 IS EMPTY - edit again:

```
update e_tbl 
set empty_column = desiredcolumn 
                    from   database2.table2 big_tbl
                    INNER JOIN database1.table1 e_tbl on e_tbl.column = 
                     big_tbl.column
                    where big_tbl.id <10 000 000
                     and big_tbl.id > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, should I be doing the where clause on table 1 (my new table) or table 2 (the massive table)?

Comment: If table 1 is empty you don't need the join

Comment: Thanks, but the field I am bringing in are unique IDs that match with other unique IDs, so I think I need to join to ensure that the correct IDs are imported?

Comment: Only one column in table 1 is empty, I am trying to bring in data that is correct as per the other columns, that are populated.

Comment: ok, you are correct.  I think I want to update my table using a left join on table 2, but with where clauses on table 2 as you suggested to make it manageable. Could I use a subquery to do this? Does this sound correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try a temp table.  Teradata or SQL Server?

SQL Server

```
SELECT desiredcolumn 
into #temp
from database2.table2 
INNER JOIN database1.table1 
on table1.column = table2.column;

INSERT INTO database1.table1 (empty column) 
SELECT desiredcolumn 
from #temp;
```

Teradata

```
Create volatile Table TempTable as (
    SELECT desiredcolumn 
    from database2.table2 
    INNER JOIN database1.table1 
    on table1.column = table2.column
) with data
on commit preserve rows;

INSERT INTO database1.table1 (empty column) 
SELECT desiredcolumn 
from TempTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, its teradata I am using.  I tried this and still got the 2646 no more spool space error.  Could I combine this with a where clause as in the suggestion above and perform repeatedly?

Comment: The tag is `sql` but not `sql server` :-)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, should I change the tag from SQL to SQL-Server?